# How to retrieve or filter all first member values of an object in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter

In node.js i have an object like this :

```
let heroes = [
    {
      signal_market: 'ENJUSDT',
      signal_initial_price: 1.33607,
      signal_last_price: 1.33607
    },
    {
      signal_market: 'DREPUSDT',
      signal_initial_price: 0.007097,
      signal_last_price: 0.007097
    },
    {
      signal_market: 'KAVAUSDT',
      signal_initial_price: 4.1702,
      signal_last_price: 4.1702
    },
    {
      signal_market: 'OGUSDT',
      signal_initial_price: 4.775,
      signal_last_price: 4.775
    },
    {
      signal_market: 'BTCUSDT',
      signal_initial_price: 0.046353,
      signal_last_price: 0.046353
    }
];
```

With the basis of this object, i wonder how to make an variable named '`targetCoins`' that contain '`ENJUSDT,DREPUSDT,KAVAUSDT,OGUSDT,BTCUSDT`' in right way without using loop?

```
targetCoins = 'ENJUSDT,DREPUSDT,KAVAUSDT,OGUSDT,BTCUSDT';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work (now tested!):

```js
const targetCoins = heroes.map((x) => x.signal_market).join(",");
```

`map` basically just iterates through the elements and transforms them in some way before putting the result in an array. `.join(",")` transforms an array into a string separated by the string `","`.

```js
let heroes = [
    {
      signal_market: 'ENJUSDT',
      signal_initial_price: 1.33607,
      signal_last_price: 1.33607
    },
    {
      signal_market: 'DREPUSDT',
      signal_initial_price: 0.007097,
      signal_last_price: 0.007097
    },
    {
      signal_market: 'KAVAUSDT',
      signal_initial_price: 4.1702,
      signal_last_price: 4.1702
    },
    {
      signal_market: 'OGUSDT',
      signal_initial_price: 4.775,
      signal_last_price: 4.775
    },
    {
      signal_market: 'BTCUSDT',
      signal_initial_price: 0.046353,
      signal_last_price: 0.046353
    }
];

const targetCoins = heroes.map((x) => x.signal_market).join(",");
console.log(targetCoins);
```

EDIT:

Just noticed you want it as a string so added `.join(",")` on the end.
Tested and added a runnable version of the code!

Answer (score 1):

If you need a comma separated string, you'll need to join it after mapping:
`const targetCoins = heroes.map(el => el.signal_market).join(',');`